# Authenticate by username or email fails with DBAL Exception: Undefined offset: 1

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4

Beginning with successful authentication by email (in 4.2.4), an attempt to follow [User Provider docs](https://symfony.com/doc/master/security/user_provider.html#security-entity-user-provider) to add authentication by username fails with

> DBAL Exception:... Undefined offset: 1

Curiously, if I run the SQL statement as shown in the debug profiler, `View runnable query`, the query runs properly and returns a non null result. So at least the repository can return a username.

I've tried rewriting the query builder statement using `entityManager`; providing a `setParameters()` statement with two parameters; all to no avail.

Edit #2:

Poking at the Doctrine code as identified in the trace (see below), the exception occurs at the line

`[$query, $params, $types] = SQLParserUtils::expandListParameters($query, $params, $types);`

The `$query` and `$params` (as shown with `dd(...)`) make sense to me. The `$types` variable, however, is opaque: it's an array `[0 => 102, 1 => 102]`. The exception occurs with the statement `SQLParserUtils...`.

end Edit #2

Edit #3:

Here's what happens in Doctrine, but I have no idea of the intent of the code. In `Doctrine\DBAL\SQLParserUtils`, lines 129 - 133, are contained in a `foreach ()` loop, run once for each element in the `$paramsPos` array `[0 => 496, 1 => 513]`, where the values are the location of the replaceable parameters in a SQL statement. The $params array initially contains

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "username" => "gbrooks"
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    "username" => "gbrooks"
  ]
]
```

After the code in 125 - 133 (as seen below) is executed

```
$needle    += $paramOffset;
$needlePos += $queryOffset;
$count      = count($params[$needle]);

$params = array_merge(
    array_slice($params, 0, $needle),
    $params[$needle],
    array_slice($params, $needle + 1)
);
```

the `$params` array contains

```
array:2 [▼
  "username" => "gbrooks"
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "username" => "gbrooks"
  ]
]
```

Note there no longer exists a key `1`, so when the `count($params[$needle])` statement at line 127 is encountered in the next pass through the loop (and `$needle` is now 1, the `DBAL Exception Undefined offset: 1` is thrown.

end Edit #3

UserRepository:

```
namespace App\Repository;

use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Security\User\UserLoaderInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class UserRepository extends EntityRepository implements UserLoaderInterface
{
    public function loadUserByUsername($usernameOrEmail)
    {
        $user = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->where('u.username = :query OR u.email = :query')
            ->setParameter('query', $usernameOrEmail)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult();
    }
}
```

LoginFormAuthenticator contains:

```
public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
{
    $token = new CsrfToken('authenticate', $credentials['csrf_token']);
    if (!$this->csrfTokenManager->isTokenValid($token)) {
        throw new InvalidCsrfTokenException();
    }

    $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->loadUserByUsername(['username' => $credentials['username']]);

    if (!$user) {
        // fail authentication with a custom error
        throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Email could not be found.');
    }

    return $user;
}
```

Trace:

```
G:\Documents\workspace\mana\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException.php:172 {▶}
  G:\Documents\workspace\mana\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException.php:145 {▶}
  G:\Documents\workspace\mana\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Connection.php:911 {▶}
  G:\Documents\workspace\mana\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Exec\SingleSelectExecutor.php:50 {▶}
  G:\Documents\workspace\mana\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Query.php:334 {▶}
  G:\Documents\workspace\mana\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery.php:967 {▶}
  G:\Documents\workspace\mana\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery.php:922 {▶}
  G:\Documents\workspace\mana\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery.php:765 {▶}
  G:\Documents\workspace\mana\src\Repository\UserRepository.php:24 {▶}
  G:\Documents\workspace\mana\src\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator.php:74 {▶}
  G:\Documents\workspace\mana\vendor\symfony\security-guard\Provider\GuardAuthenticationProvider.php:102 {▶}
  G:\Documents\workspace\mana\vendor\symfony\security-guard\Provider\GuardAuthenticationProvider.php:96 {▶}
  G:\Documents\workspace\mana\vendor\symfony\security-core\Authentication\AuthenticationProviderManager.php:76 {▶}
  G:\Documents\workspace\mana\vendor\symfony\security-guard\Firewall\GuardAuthenticationListener.php:130 {▶}
  G:\Documents\workspace\mana\vendor\symfony\security-guard\Firewall\GuardAuthenticationListener.php:82 {▶}
  G:\Documents\workspace\mana\vendor\symfony\security-bundle\Debug\WrappedListener.php:46 {▶}
  G:\Documents\workspace\mana\vendor\symfony\security-bundle\Debug\TraceableFirewallListener.php:35 {▶}
  G:\Documents\workspace\mana\vendor\symfony\security-http\Firewall.php:90 {▶}
  G:\Documents\workspace\mana\vendor\symfony\security-bundle\EventListener\FirewallListener.php:48 {▶}
  G:\Documents\workspace\mana\vendor\symfony\event-dispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener.php:115 {▶}
  G:\Documents\workspace\mana\vendor\symfony\event-dispatcher\EventDispatcher.php:212 {▶}
  G:\Documents\workspace\mana\vendor\symfony\event-dispatcher\EventDispatcher.php:44 {▶}
  G:\Documents\workspace\mana\vendor\symfony\event-dispatcher\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher.php:145 {▶}
  G:\Documents\workspace\mana\vendor\symfony\http-kernel\HttpKernel.php:126 {▶}
  G:\Documents\workspace\mana\vendor\symfony\http-kernel\HttpKernel.php:67 {▶}
  G:\Documents\workspace\mana\vendor\symfony\http-kernel\Kernel.php:198 {▶}
  G:\Documents\workspace\mana\public\index.php:25 {▶}
```

Comment: You should really add the full error trace you get, not just a snipped version of it (as it will point out what is the line/file raising it). Also for the info there is a shortcut to `dump('test');die;` in SF4: `dd('test');` ;)

Comment: For improving your code. In Symfony 4 it is a good practice to inject the repository what you need and not the entityManager. So you can inject UserRepository by constructor and do a $this->userRepository->loadUserByUsername

Comment: Trace is appended. I'm not clever enough to sort things out in Doctrine code. Thnx for tip on `dd()` though. btw, I always try to follow docs at first, tidy later.

Comment: What version of doctrine are you using?

Comment: Assuming you're interested in doctrine/dbal: 2.9.2

Comment: I've added Edit #3 that details the Doctrine\DBAL code that throws the exception. How to work around this code remains a mystery to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole problem was that the argument of `this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->loadUserByUsername(...)` should NOT be an array but a scalar.

Perhaps I can make a business out of creating Alice-like rabbit holes for falling into.

Answer (score 0):

Update your Repository to this:

```
namespace App\Repository;

use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Security\User\UserLoaderInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class UserRepository extends EntityRepository implements UserLoaderInterface
{
    public function loadUserByUsername($usernameOrEmail)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->where('u.username = :query')
            ->orWhere('u.email = :query')
            ->setParameter('query', $usernameOrEmail)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: Unsurprisingly this makes no difference.